# Error : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driverr][SQL Server]Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans-6.9

I am using MS SQL Server 2005 with Netbeans 6.9 for my Java Project.

Here's my Table structure (inside SSMS 2005) :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwTuH.png

Now, in Netbeans, I am using this code snippet to save an entered name into the 'name' column :

```
 if(e.getSource().equals(submit))
    {
        try
        {
            String str="insert into TETRISUSERS values(?,'0')";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:java","sa", "123456");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(str);
            stmt.setString(1,username.getText());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(name1,"Error : "+ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Now when I run the project and enter a name, I get the following error :

**Error : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driverr][SQL Server]Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

I also tried using using direct column names in the insert into command like below :

```
   try
        {
            String str="insert into TETRISUSERS(ID,name,highscore) values(?,'0',?)";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:java","sa", "007007");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(str);
            stmt.setString(1,username.getText());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
```

But that way I get this error :

**Error : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Serever Driver]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error**

Lastly, I tried using this :

```
try
        {
            String str="insert into TETRISUSERS(ID,name) values(?,'0')";
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:java","sa", "007007");
            PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(str);
            stmt.setString(1,username.getText());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
```

And I got this Error :

**Error: General Error**

Can Anyone please guide me where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your picture none of the columns allow null values.  If you pass null values for any of the columns its going to barf.  So try passing a value for every column and you will likely have different and likely better results.

Comment: I just made all the columns to 'Allow null'... But the program is still giving the same errors :(

Comment: Last guess stmt.setString(1,username.getText()); Is 1 the first param to be passed? Id is an Int so probably should be stmt.setInt(0,1) right?

Comment: Yes, ID was the first param to be passed.. But I am not sure how to use seInt when the 2nd param is a variable.. :s

Comment: Also, I just tried setting ID to be nvarchar in my table, and tried using the same syntax in my program.. but getting the same errors :(

Comment: SetInt(parameterIndex,parameterValue); So SetInt(0,1) SetInt(2,3)

Comment: the index should be 0 for the first parameter and 1 for the 2nd and 2 for the 3rd if you are using the Set methods

Comment: Ok, I just edited the code and did this as you said :


            `try
            {
                String str="insert into TETRISUSERS values(?,'0')";
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:java","sa", "007007");
                PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(str);
                stmt.setInt(0,1);
                stmt.setString(1,username.getText());
                
                stmt.executeUpdate();
            }`

And now I get this error :

Error: -1

Comment: You are only accepting one param there right? Only 1 ? in your query.

Comment: Oh, I just set the ID to increment automatically.. and program is now working fine with the initial code :)
Thanks a lot awright !